# 3 classes with getter-setter

Tags: java, class, encapsulation, getter-setter

I created 3 classes to separate the functionality of each class.

---

1st - InputOutput class which accepts input and prints output only

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class InputOutput {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GetterSetter obj = new GetterSetter();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input 1st num: ");
        int a = input.nextInt();
        obj.setNum1(a);
        System.out.print("Input 2nd num: ");
        int b = input.nextInt();
        obj.setNum2(b);
        System.out.println(obj.getSum());

    }
}
```

2nd class- GetterSetter class which gets and sets data.

```
public class GetterSetter {
    private int num1;
    private int num2;
    private int sum;

    public int getNum1() {
        return num1;
    }
    public void setNum1(int num1) {
        this.num1 = num1;
    }
    public int getNum2() {
        return num2;
    }
    public void setNum2(int num2) {
        this.num2 = num2;
    }
    public int getSum() {
        return sum;
    }
    public void setSum(int sum) {
        this.sum = sum;
    }    
}
```

3rd - Process class which process the data(contains all the logic in the program).

```
public class Process {

    GetterSetter obj = new GetterSetter();
        int num1 = obj.getNum1();
        int num2 = obj.getNum2();
        int sum = num1 + num2;
        obj.setSum(sum);//error
}
```

---

How can I make the process class come into action?

How can I achieve this:

1. get data from InputOutput class
2. set gathered data to GetterSetter class
3. in the process class, get data from GetterSetter class -> do the operations -> set the result to the GetterSetter class.
4. lastly, print the output/result in the InputOutput class.

Comment: 1) What is the Model class (GetterSetter?)? 2) What is the app class? 3) In part 3, what's wrong with what you're currently doing? 4) When is the homework due by?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to follow an MVC pattern here. Here's a good reference on how this works: [MVC](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/mvc_pattern.htm) I would suggest completing this tutorial, and fitting it to your current application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `extends` keyword to get all the info from your class `InputOutput`. You could try this:

```
public class GetterSetter extends InputOutput
{
    /*** Code from your GetterSetter class ***/
}
```

Then you can use the info from your `GetterSetter` class and extend it to your `Process` class.

```
public class Process extends GetterSetter
{
    /*** Code from your Process class ***/        
}
```

Now you can use all the variables from your `InputOutput` class within your other two classes.

Within your `Process` class, you could use a `toString()` method to override the `System.out.println(obj.getSum());`.

The `toString()` should look something similar to this:

```
public String toString(num1, num2, sum)
{
    String sumString = "" + sum;
    return sumString;
}
```

And instead of calling the `System.out.println()` that you're using, call the `toString()` method and print it.

```
System.out.println(toString(a, b));
```

Hope this helped somewhat with what you're doing.